# how to get uuid of a device using udev

Tags: python, udev

I want get the mount node of an usb mass-storage device, like /media/its-uuid
in pyudev, class Device has some general attributes, but not uuid or mount node.

how to do it

thanks help

Answer (score 2):

With pyudev, each device object provides a dictionary-like interface for its attributes. You can list them all with `device.keys()`, e.g. UUID is for block devices is `dev['ID_FS_UUID']`.

Comment: This only works on partition devices E.g. /dev/sda. This does not work on block devices. E.g. /dev/sda

Answer (score 0):

This will print the UUID of every USB flash disk currently plugged in along with its device node:

```
import pyudev

context = pyudev.Context()

for device in context.list_devices(subsystem='block', DEVTYPE='partition'):
    if (device.get('ID_USB_DRIVER') == 'usb-storage'):
        print '{0} {1}'.format(device.device_node, device.get('ID_FS_UUID'))
```